# How to install GMP PHP package on Mac

Tags: php, composer-php, gmp

I need to install `web-token/jwt-framework` on MacOS High Sierra using composer. So, I use command `composer require web-token/jwt-framework`. When I do that, I get this error message in terminal:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - web-token/jwt-framework v1.3.8 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
```

I tried to go to https://gmplib.org/#DOWNLOAD but there is nothing on how to actually install gmp, and thus incorporating it into my PHP. I did not try out setting it up in PHP.INI because  I haven't yet did anything to install it. Any advice?

Comment: `brew search gmp` should tell you if it is available for Sierra.

Comment: I did that and it shows a checked sign and text: ==> Formulae
gmp ✔

Comment: then it is already installed on your box ! what does `php -m` tell you at the command line ? should show gmp.

Comment: err, no. It is not in the list......

Comment: did you install php with brew or is it the brain-dead version apple ships ?

Comment: I think I installed the brain dead version.

Comment: MAMP PHP. I use PHP 7.3.1 from MAMP. This is what is used in the terminal. Watch your language too.